# Make a dynamic Builder Filter for different types of nested documents - MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, filtering

I have a collection named `some_collection`. The schema for `some_collection` is like this: (The schema is dictated by the C# DTO)

```
{
   _id: ObjectId(.....),
   firstName: "fName",
   lastName: "lName",
   someType: 4, 
   innerObject: {
      // see below
   }
}
```

In my C# code, innerObject is an abstract class, and has multiple children classes. These children classes have variant properties, thus the documents in the MongoDB collection aren't all the same. The type of child class they are is demarcated by the `someType` field in an individual `some_collection` document. So, examples of 2 documents in `audit_collection` that have 2 different types of nested documents:

```
   {
       _id: ObjectId('first'),
       firstName: "Jane",
       lastName: "Smith",
       someType: 0, 
       innerObject: {
          prop1: "foo",
          prop2: "bar",
          aCollectionOfStrings: ["a", "b", "c"] // this is what I wanna search
       }
    },
{
   _id: ObjectId('second'),
   firstName: "John",
   lastName: "Doe",
   someType: 3, 
   innerObject: {
      prop1: "baz",
      prop2: "foobarbaz",
      aCollectionOfObjects: [
          {
            myProp: "hello", // this is what I want to search
            irrelevantProp: "blah" 
          }, 
          {
            myProp: "hello5", // this is what I want to search
            irrelevantProp: "blah" 
          },
          {
            myProp: "hello1", // this is what I want to search
            irrelevantProp: "blah" 
          }
      ] 
   }
}
```

The use case for this question is that I want to search for a string provided by a user, and this can exist in the `firstname` and `lastname` properties (which is at the top level of the document, and all the documents share it, so easy enough), and also some of the inner properties of the objects (since the nested inner documents are different in schema, it is more difficult to do). So for example:

For `someType == 0`, I'd search `myDocument.innerObject.aCollectionOfStrings`, whereas with `someType == 3`, I'd search **each** `myDocument.innerObject.aCollectionOfObjects`'s `myProp` property.

In my C# code, if I pull the full collection, and then use LINQ operations on it, I have a C# function that determines **how** to search the full document (basically it checks the value of `someType`, and then based on that, it *knows* which properties to search), along with its nested document, and can do the filtration in the C# code.

However, after refactoring to using Builders Filters, I can't pass that C# filter function into the Filter (obviously, since all the Builder is doing is building a MongoDB query, I think):

`filter = filter & Builders<MyOwnType>.Filter.Eq(a => CheckIfObjectHasString(a, search), true);`

Where `CheckIfObjectHasString` is something like:

```
private bool CheckIfObjectHasString(MyOwnType doc, string search)
{
   if(doc.someType == 0)
   {
     return doc.innerObject.aCollectionOfStrings.Where(s => s.ToLower().Contains(search)).Any();
   } else if(doc.someType == 3) {
     return doc.innerObject.aCollectionOfObjects.Where(d => d.myProp.ToLower().Contains(search)).Any();
   } else if(...)
   {
       // etc.
   } 
}
```

One solution to this I thought of is maybe during document insertion, create a property on the `some_collection` document at the top-most level, that has all the searchable material, but that seems to be unclean. How can I build a filter like the above, without resorting to doing the processing in LINQ or the solution I just mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was making raw `BsonDocument`s comparable to what I was looking for, and `$or`ing them, and embedding the `$regex` in the `BsonDocuments` for their respective fields.  I was unaware that when searching for documents in MongoDB, without the use of application code, your query is a document to compare against.

```
private BsonDocument FindSearch(string searchString)
{
   // escape the searchString

   var filterDocument = new BsonDocument();
   var searchDocument = new BsonDocument();
   searchDocument.Add(("$regex", $".*{searchString}.*"));
   searchDocument.Add("$options", "i"); // to ignore case when performing the regex

   var searchCriterias = new BsonArray(); // an array because I'll be $or-ing it
   searchCriterias.Add(new BsonDocument("innerObject.aCollectionOfObjects.myProp", textSearch)); // access each nested object's property
   searchCriterias.Add(new BsonDocument("innerObject.aCollectionOfStrings", textSearch)); // even though it's an array of strings, I can just search without having to iterate them

   filterDocument.Add("$or", searchCriterias); // $or-ing it also saved me from having to check the existence of properties, before doing the search
}
```

And then, even though it's a `BsonDocument`, I was able to use it with my already existing `Builders` `Filter`s e.g.:

`existingFilter = existingFilter | FindSearch(theSearch); // existingFilter is FilterDefinition<MyOwnType>`